# Who was the last Emperor of England?

Tags: england

Queen Victoria assumed I guess in 1865 the title of Empress, do you know if and when that title was dropped?

Comment: When the British Empire was disbanded.

Comment: @MoziburUllah, when was that? with the independence of India?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: @Charlie: you can check that on Wikipedia. See comment above ;-).

Comment: [Welcome](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4053) to HistorySE, [USERNAME]! What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks! Was Vicky 'empress _of England'?_ It's hard to tell what you want to know exactly. 'When did the British Empire stop to be a thing'?

Comment: @LаngLаngС, that link doesn't' help, there are many dates considered as the end of the empire, what my question asked if later Kings actually used that title. Thanks, anyway, I'll delete my question

Comment: Or update it to clarify!

Comment: The [Statute in Restraint of Appeals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_in_Restraint_of_Appeals) 1532 (Henry VIII) declared England an empire, stating it was not subject to higher authority such as the Pope or Holy Roman Emperor.  It seem to have been repealed in the 1960s but the concept is probably still UK law.

Comment: Queen Victoria's title was Empress of India. India itself was an empire, with many princely and other states.. The British empire itself never had an empress or emperor, but just a king. The late Queen's father was Emperor of India until June 1948, that is even after India and Pakistan became independent, but before either became republics.

Comment: @Charlie   A number of Romaanusurpers and successful emperorsreigned in parts of the empire which included Britain.  It is quite possible that some of the Romano-British rulers in post Roman Britain claimed to be Roman Emperors.  In the 530s Procopius wrote that Britain hade been ruled by "tryants" which should mean Roman usurpers not recognized as epmerors by legitimate emperors.  Some of the Anglo-Saxon  kings of the English in the 10th and 11th centuries used titles imitating those of eastern Roman or 'Byzantine" Emperors and Holy Roman Emperors. Continued:

Comment: @charlie  Continued:  In 1532 a law of Henry VIII declard that England ws "an empire", meaning a claim to independent of any Roman Empire or the papacy.     And:  In 1801 the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland was created after the merging of the British and Irish parliaments. It was suggested that George III be declared Emperor of the British Isles. He declined and became king of "the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland".[10]   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Emperor  And those are the only examples I culd find of any thing remotely like an English or British "empire"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is like I suggested is easily available on Wikipedia. It says the late Queen Elizabeth II father, George VI was the last emperor of India (not England - but of course his home was in England) until August 1947 when the British Raj was dissolved.

There are no pretenders to the title, even if they might style themselves like that to themselves or their friends. They are not fooling anyone except themselves (in their own minds).  In fact, people who style themselves Emperors of England usually belong to a mental asylum, that is a psychiatric clinic. Though usually I've heard , apocraphally, that its usually Emperor Napoleon of France or the Pope or the like. But why not Emperor of England - seems just as likely to me.